# Accessing member variable of a class containing a thread

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading

```cpp
 //function creating my class and thread        
 extractor = new FeatureExtractor(receiveBufferCurrent);
            HANDLE   hth1;
            unsigned  uiThread1ID;

            hth1 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL,         
                0,            
                FeatureExtractor::ThreadStaticEntryPoint,
                extractor,           
                CREATE_SUSPENDED,  
                &uiThread1ID);
```

```
//Header file
class FeatureExtractor
{
private:
    float sensorData[200][10];

public:
    FeatureExtractor(float receiveBufferCurrent[][10]);
    ~FeatureExtractor();

    //Thread for parallel input and motion detection
    static unsigned int __stdcall ThreadStaticEntryPoint(void * pThis);
    void ThreadEntryPoint();
    void outputTest();
};
```

```cpp
FeatureExtractor::FeatureExtractor(float receiveBufferCurrent[][10])
{
memcpy(sensorData, receiveBufferCurrent, sizeof(sensorData));
}

unsigned __stdcall FeatureExtractor::ThreadStaticEntryPoint(void * pThis)
{
    FeatureExtractor * pthX = (FeatureExtractor*)pThis;  
    pthX->ThreadEntryPoint();           
    return 1;  
}

void FeatureExtractor::ThreadEntryPoint()
{
    outputTest();
}
```

```cpp
//output function
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i = i + 50)
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "AccelX=" << sensorData[i][1] << ", AccelY=" << sensorData[i][2] << ", AccelZ=" << sensorData[i][3] << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "MagX=" << sensorData[i][4] << ", MagY=" << sensorData[i][5] << ", MagZ=" << sensorData[i][6] << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "GyroX=" << sensorData[i][7] << ", GyroY=" << sensorData[i][8] << ", GyroZ=" << sensorData[i][9] << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    }
```

I have some problem with accessing the float array "sensorData" inside a thread.
If I output the sensorData array inside the constructor everything is fine but if I access the array from inside my thread my array just contains -1.58839967e+038 which I guess means that I cannot access my array in this way from a thread.

What am I doing wrong?

I got the thread code from a tutorial which accesses class member variables in the same way although just integers not multi dimensional arrays.

I tried to minimize the length of my code snippets while keeping the important parts, I'm thankful for anybody taking the time to analyze my code!

Comment: What is `receiveBufferCurrent` and how is it initialized? How do you print `sensorData`? Can you perhaps create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: pleas show the piece of code how you are displaying the sensor data.

Comment: I edited my post and showed the display function for the sensor data (I used exactly the same code to display sensorData inside the constructor and it worked).
receiveBufferCurrent is the array I'm passing to the constructor and copy it into sensorData (I already verified that sensorData has the correct data after the FeatureExtractor object is created)
Thank your for trying to help!

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg : I created an example like this, it should show my problem. I uploaded the source here: http://filebin.ca/1zNcA7EWhNMQ/Thread_Problem_Example.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself now.

```
            WaitForSingleObject(hth1, INFINITE);
```

Once I waited for my thread the issue has been resolved.
The issue occurred because I deleted my class before it could finish execution.
It also worked to simple remove the delete statement.